# Solving for two variables in a density function without an expected value.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have been given the piece-wise function $f(x)$ to define a density function.
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) =\begin{cases}
a+bx^2, & \text{if}\,\,0\leq x\leq 0.69\\
0,      & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

I want to find the variables $a$ and $b$. I am not given an expected value $E[x]$.
I thought that I could use the definition of a density function, that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1$ to solve for the variables, but I do not have the expected value to use when doing a system of equations to find the variables.

I suspect that integrating over $0\leq x\leq 0.69$ has something to do with how the solution is reached, but I cannot figure out how to solve for both variables without the expected value.

Comment: Since $f(x)$ is zero except when $0\leq x\leq 0.69$, where it equals $(a+bx^2)$, you have: $$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm d x &= \int_{-\infty}^0 0\,\mathrm d x+\int_0^{0.69} (a+bx^2)\,\mathrm d x+ \int_{0.69}^\infty 0\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex]\therefore\qquad1&=\int_0^{0.69} (a+bx^2)\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$$ See bravoralph 's answer for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you no longer have any conditions prevents you from finding unique solutions. On the other hand, you can generate infinities, if, as you say, you integrate on the support of your variable, which is the interval $[0,0.69]$, and set it equal to $1$ to obtain an equation in two variables. The other thing is to take into account that your density must be non-negative, thus restricting the set of admissible values for $a$ and $b$. Try it.